# hamburger menu not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, hamburger-menu

I am trying to learn how hamburger menu works. It is not working. I have tried adding 'ready function' as well nothing changes. I am writing js code in html with script tag, should i mention js code separately?

```js
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".cross" ).hide();
$( ".menu" ).hide();
$( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
$( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
$( ".hamburger" ).hide();
$( ".cross" ).show();
});
});

$( ".cross" ).click(function() {
$( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
$( ".cross" ).hide();
$( ".hamburger" ).show();
});
});

});

</script>
```

```css
body{
  font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 margin:0;
  background-image: url('https://unsplash.imgix.net/41/yEWFnFQRqfmY9l9efJ6g_Snap01-web.jpg?q=75&w=1080&h=1080&fit=max&fm=jpg&auto=format&s=7580de2dc3b3821f0dc1c97f2d60fe7c');
}
header{

    width:100%; 
 background:#1d1f20; 
 height:50px; 
 line-height:50px;
}

.hamburger{
  background:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  line-height:45px;
  padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
  color:#fff;
  border:0;
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  z-index:10000000000000;
}
.cross{
  background:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0;
  padding:0px 15px 0px 15px;
  color:#fff;
  border:0;
  font-size:3em;
  line-height:65px;
  font-weight:bold;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  z-index:10000000000000;
}
.menu{z-index:1000000; font-weight:bold; font-size:0.8em; width:100%; background:#131313;  position:absolute; text-align:center;}
.menu ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; list-style-image: none;}
.menu li {display: block;   padding:15px 0 15px 0; border-bottom:#1d1f20 1px solid;}
.menu li:hover{display: block;    background:#181818; padding:15px 0 15px 0; border-bottom:#1d1f20 1px solid;}
.menu ul li a { text-decoration:none;  margin: 0px; color:#fff;}
.menu ul li a:hover {  color: #fff; text-decoration:none;}
.menu a{text-decoration:none; color:white;}
.menu a:hover{text-decoration:none; color:white;}

.glyphicon-home{
  color:white; 
  font-size:1.5em; 
  margin-top:5px; 
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="new9.css"/>
 </head>
 
<header>
  <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
  <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
</header>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK ONE</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK TWO</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK THREE</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK FOUR</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>LINK FIVE</li></a>
  </ul>
</div> 

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import jQuery to your header.

```
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="new9.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: It's Working. Thanks @hetasbo